# Universal App - Transparent Buttons in the title bar?

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, win-universal-app, windows-10

So I have this code

```
        var applicationView = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView();
        var titleBar = applicationView.TitleBar;

        CoreApplication.GetCurrentView().TitleBar.ExtendViewIntoTitleBar = true;

        titleBar.ButtonBackgroundColor = Colors.Transparent;
        titleBar.ButtonForegroundColor = Colors.White;
```

But the menu buttons (Close, Minimize, Maximize) do not have the transparent background as specified. Even if I use an ARGB and set them that way, it seems as though the alpha value is ignored. Is there any way to set them to be transparent?

Answer (score 0):

Setting ButtonBackgroundColor (etc.) to Colors.Transparent should work. I confirmed that your code lets my background image show through on current builds. If you're not on 10158 yet upgrade and give it a try.

Comment: Is this still true? I have version 1709 and only the background can be transparent. ButtonForegroundColor cannot. Though I can set it to other colors. Perhaps a security measure?